# How to get the height of UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

What i am trying to do is, adding a `UIScrollView` and inside scroll `UIView` and inside `UIView` 2 label with dynamic height. Now i want to set the height of UIScrollView to be scrolled at the bottom of the page.
But right now i am getting infinite scroll. Can anyone help me with this code ?

```
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 155.0, 320, 513)];
UIView *myview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 155.0, 320.0, FLT_MAX)];

UILabel *lable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 155.0, 320.0, FLT_MAX)];
lable.numberOfLines = 0;
lable.text = @"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).";
[lable sizeToFit];

UILabel *slabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 480.0, 320.0, FLT_MAX)];
slabel.numberOfLines = 0;

slabel.text = @” It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).”;
[slabel sizeToFit];

scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollview.contentSize.width, myview.frame.size.height);

[myview addSubview:lable];
[myview addSubview:slabel];
[scrollview addSubview:myview];
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
```

Comment: `FLT_MAX`...? and what do you exactly hope to get from that small value of `3.40282347E+38F`?

Comment: The correct place to put such a piece of code is in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. Where exactly you've placed this code? And last where abouts you're setting `contentOffset` on your `scrollView`?

Comment: holex ... i am a beginner in iOS and i am trying to get this done. i have 4 column in database want to display in UILable in a UIScrollView. so what i am thinking to do is .. make a for loop and write the data in UILable for all 4 column but the problem is that i dont know how much line of code that all 4 column will contain.

Comment: Panayot Panayotov i have placed this code inside the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

you should apply this code i apply height of scrollview 480 [for normal iphone size] and apply label font HelveticaNeue-Bold,

```
     UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 480)];

    UIView *myview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 320.0, 400)];
    [myview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    UILabel *lable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 320.0, FLT_MAX)];
    lable.numberOfLines = 0;

    [lable setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0]];
    NSString *strText = @"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).";
    float y = 0;
    CGSize textViewSize = [strText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0]
                                  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, FLT_MAX)
                                      lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    [lable setText:strText];
    [lable setFrame:CGRectMake(lable.frame.origin.x, lable.frame.origin.y, 320,roundf(textViewSize.height))];

   [myview addSubview:lable];

    y = lable.frame.origin.y+textViewSize.height;
    UILabel *slabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, y, 320.0, FLT_MAX)];
    slabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [slabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14.0]];
    //the text of both label is same thats why we use same height used for first one

    slabel.text = @"It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).";
    [slabel setText:strText];
    [slabel setFrame:CGRectMake(slabel.frame.origin.x, y, 320,roundf(textViewSize.height))];

    y = slabel.frame.origin.y+textViewSize.height;

    [myview addSubview:slabel];
    [myview setFrame:CGRectMake(0,myview.frame.origin.y,myview.frame.size.width,y)];       
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollview.contentSize.width, myview.frame.size.height+15);


    [scrollview addSubview:myview];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
```